# Is there a way to synchronize only part of Firefox bookmarks?

Tags: firefox, bookmark, synchronization

Is there a way to synchronise only a part of Firefox bookmarks?

I'm trying to find a solution, it may be a plugin, third party app, anything, that allows to sync only selected bookmarks (by folder/tag/anything else).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Xmarks](https://www.xmarks.com), available as Firefox plugin: its '[Sync profiles](https://www.xmarks.com/about/features/sync_profiles)' functions allows you to create lists of bookmarks you want to sync and let you choose to which devices you want to sync them. Also, you can select folders you want to sync. The downside is that you need to create a Xmarks account to use it. [Here](https://download.xmarks.com/download/firefox) the link to the Firefox plugin download.